# Haya (Shyness) and how to restore it?

Tags: self-defense, self-purification

Assalam-o-Alaikum, Brothers and Sisters.
I was listening to a very famous Islamic scholar who said and I quote:

> **Once you left Haya' from your eyes, It will never return to you. There is no cure for this.**

There is a hadith for this

> **إِنَّ أَوَّلَ مَا يُرْفَعُ مِنْ هَذِهِ الأُمَّةِ الْحَيَاءُ وَالأَمَانَةُ ، فَسَلُوهُمَا اللَّهَ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ**
>   **Verily the first that this Ummah will lose is the shyness (Haya') and trust so keep asking them Allah the almighty.**

I just wanted to ask this community that is there any way to return Haya to ourselves? There is a cure to almost everything, is there any for this? I couldn't find any satisfactory explanation for this.
Jazak Allah for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haya is an important factor that many should be eager to hold.
The Prophet (s) said, “Faith (Belief) consists of more than sixty branches (i.e. parts). And Haya’ is a part of faith.” (Bukhari)
The Prophet (s) said: “Al-haya’u la ya’ti illa bi khayr”, Haya’ will not bring anything except good. (Sahih al-Bukhari)

Haya comes in a natural form since birth and other factors such as envuronmental factors and ethics can impact it too.

Here is a suggestion for a cure:
The stronger your belief is in Allah the more you will realose you are in the presence of Allah and this connection may help trigger Haya.
If you can you may want to try read Quran more, pray more maybe tahajjud etc. Also try to abstain from doing impermissible things and wrongful things. Try not to backbite or use bad language, try reduce the time you may spend talking to mahram individuals.

The stronger your faith is it may cause more Haya and this can be a cure from such a fall. Try to cut off the things that cut off your Haya whether it is out of your comfort zone try to make an effort and it may benefit you.

Haya may encourage things that strengthen iman and discourage things that weaken it and this is essential.

Comment: http://religion4humanity.blogspot.com/2014/02/haya-modesty-innate-character-of-islam.html?m=1 This link may help too

Comment: Jazak Allah, I will surely try my best. May Allah help me.